# Difference between EVP_PKEY_sign and EVP_DigestSignInit?

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, rsa, libcrypto

So far I've seen two different approaches to RSA signing with OpenSSL:
With **EVP_PKEY_sign**

```
 ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(signing_key, NULL /* no engine */);
 if (!ctx)
     /* Error occurred */
 if (EVP_PKEY_sign_init(ctx) <= 0)
     /* Error */
 if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING) <= 0)
     /* Error */
 if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_signature_md(ctx, EVP_sha256()) <= 0)
     /* Error */

 /* Determine buffer length */
 if (EVP_PKEY_sign(ctx, NULL, &siglen, md, mdlen) <= 0)
```

With **EVP_DigestSignInit**:

```
if(1 != EVP_DigestSignInit(mdctx, NULL, EVP_sha256(), NULL, key)) 
          goto err;
if(1 != EVP_DigestSignUpdate(mdctx, msg, strlen(msg))) 
          goto err;
if(1 != EVP_DigestSignFinal(mdctx, NULL, slen)) 
          goto err;
if(!(*sig = OPENSSL_malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * (*slen)))) 
          goto err;
if(1 != EVP_DigestSignFinal(mdctx, *sig, slen)) 
          goto err;
```

Are these just two different ways to do the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh.  There's a fairly major difference.

> EVP_PKEY_sign() does not hash the data to be signed, and therefore is normally used to sign digests. For signing arbitrary messages, see the EVP_DigestSignInit(3)

Per https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:EVP_PKEY_sign(3)

So EVP_PKEY_sign is very likely used under the hood in EVP_Digest SignInit, and is intended for applications where the caller will manually format the block to be signed.

Comment: even in spite of previous EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_signature_md call?

Comment: I can't test at the moment, but you could try handing EVP_PKEY_sign too much data (e.g., 4000 bytes) and see if it will process it...and if it does, RSA decrypt the result as RAW and check the structure to make sure it didn't ignore parts.

Comment: i have been trying to find more info on this APIs. Its been a tough process to find it out. is there a better document somewhere with more explanation ?

Comment: Using EVP_PKEY_sign together with EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_signature_md seems to accept over 20k of data during my tests.