# OpenSSL: Skip hashing while using EVP_DigestSign for creating digital signatures

Tags: openssl, cryptography, digital-signature

I'm trying to create digital signatures with OpenSSL 3 using high level EVP API.

The calling application gives me a digest to sign and not the whole plaintext. Therefore, when I call `EVP_DigestSignInit`, I need to prevent the data from being hashed again.

I tried the following:

```
EVP_PKEY* pkey = ...
size_t signatureLength = ...;

EVP_MD_CTX* ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
EVP_DigestSignInit(ctx, NULL, EVP_md_XXXXX(), NULL, pkey);
EVP_DigestSign(ctx, signature, &signatureLength, digest, digestLength);
```

What value do I have to set for the hash function? I have tried NULL and `EVP_md_null()`.
NULL gives me a SegFault and `EVP_md_null()` returns an empty hash value. What I need would be something like `EVP_md_noop()` which does nothing, but just passes the input data unchanged.

Comment: Check out [`EVP_PKEY_sign()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_PKEY_sign.html) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47690496/9014097).